estou fazendo um teste que consiste em cadastrar, visualizar e excluir contatos, porém estou tendo dificuldades para fazer a conexão com o banco
depois de fazer o migration, tendo dar o update-database é sempre aparece esse erro: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)
no chatgpt diz que é erro de conexão é que poder ser a instancia. porém não estou conseguindo acertar o erro mesmo assim.
banco:
namespace controlecontatos.Models
{
    public class BancoDeDados : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Contatomodel> Contatomodel { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString: @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=controlecontatos; Integrated Security=True");
        }

    }
}

startup.cs
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddControllersWithViews();
     services.AddDbContext<BancoDeDados>();
 }


Olá,
Eu já passei por outros erros de instalação, mas esse 52 ainda não (error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation).
Então, pesquisei um pouco e fui coletando algumas informações, acredito que o item 3 (habilite LocalDB) pode ser uma luz, pois o erro se refere as etapas iniciais de instalação do Microsoft SQL Server.

Se puder, desinstale o que tem instalado;
Verifique as versões disponíveis de acordo com seu Sistema Operacional e faça o download do Microsoft SQL Server Express (por exemplo, 2019);
Durante a nova instalação, no step de "Selecionar Recursos" (features) habilite o LocalDB (que na Central de Instalação do SQL Server por padrão vem desabilitado em "Recursos Compartilhados") e Desabilite o recurso de Machine Learning;
Mantenha os serviços da instância que será criada com inicialização "Automática";
Para autenticação escolha modo misto (autenticação via SQL Server e via Sistema Operacional);

Após a instalação, confira:

Confira o nome da instância que passou na string de conexão;
Use a ferramenta de configuração de rede do SQL Server para habilitar conexões remotas por meio de protocolo TCP/IP e pipes;
Verifique se foi configurado o firewall na instância para abrir as portas para o SQL Server(1433) e a porta do SQL Server Browser(UDP 1434);
Verifique se os serviços SQL Server e o SQL Server Browser estão com status "Em Execução";
Importante saber sobre as permissões do usuário, para descartar permissões negadas;

Geralmente as strings geralmente não possuem espaços em branco no valor da propriedade (ao longo da string entre as aspas).
Exemplo 1:
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=
NomeDoSeuBancoDeDados;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
Exemplo 2:
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=
NomeDoSeuBancoDeDados;Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=true;");
Outros links que podem ser úteis:

Recursos Microsoft SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16
SQL Server Express LocalDB: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15
Comandos iniciando database: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/
Comandos SqlLocalDB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility?view=sql-server-ver16

Espero ter ajudado, Cida Luna.
